# Angularjs - Handle checkbox value

Tags: html, angularjs

Im trying to set a checkbox to be "true" at soon as the page load (and it works fine) but as soon the page load the value is "empty".
If i click the checkbox it starts saying "true and false".

What im doing wrong here?
http://jsfiddle.net/WTN4p/13/

```
<div ng-app>
<div >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="check"/>        
</div>


check is: {{ check }}

<div ng-show="check == 'true'">
    Checked
</div>
```

Best Reguards Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define property using `ng-model`,Angular will start looking for the properties value in `$scope`. If the property is not present then it will be `undefined`.

In your case, as you aren't initialising the variable `check` before it's value is `undefined'.

Angular interpolation service is smart enough that it won't show undefined while evaluating the expression.

That's why you don't see any output in `{{check}}`.

One option to tackle this:

Set initial value of `check` in your controller.

```
$scope.check = 'true';
```

Else in your view:

```
ng-init="check = 'true'";
```

Comment: ahh Thanks, i will to $scope.check = "true";

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the initial value/state of `check`.

You could do this inside a controller:

```
$scope.check = 'true';
```

With your existing setup you can use `ng-init` in the view:

```
<div ng-init="check = 'true'">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="check"/>      
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ff23a4at/1/

Comment: And if i need to hide that checkbox, should i use a ng-if="campaign = true" or a show/hide?, if i use a show/hide, will the checkbox still be true in the "background"? @tony barnes

Comment: I believe `ng-if` would be most suitable. The checkbox will be what you define it initially, regardless of if you use `ng-if` or `ng-show`. The conditional only acts depending on the defined value.